# Does Android have a function to validate passwords?

Tags: android, validation, passwords

I'm developing an Android app and one of my tasks is to check the strength of a password.

Are there any built-in functions for checking the strength of a password?

Comment: Here is a pretty neat article discussing the subject:
http://tech.dropbox.com/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/

Comment: A link only answer below [gives this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146085/Model-Validation-Support-in-Android-Binding), and I am adding it here in case it is deleted by the Review Queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to answer the question, there is no Android function to do this, the closest and best way is to use regex as Mkyong suggested on his [blog](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-password-with-regular-expression/):

```
private Pattern pattern;
      private Matcher matcher;

      private static final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = 
              "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})";

      public PasswordValidator(){
          pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
      }

      /**
       * Validate password with regular expression
       * @param password password for validation
       * @return true valid password, false invalid password
       */
      public boolean validate(final String password){

          matcher = pattern.matcher(password);
          return matcher.matches();

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an external library such as http://code.google.com/p/vt-middleware/wiki/vtpassword etc.

Or it is simple enough to code up something like checking how long it is, what characters it has etc and printing out different things based on that.

If say a user had a 10 length password and some upper case characters you could increment some password strength parameter based on this, rewarding more complex passwords. You can set teh thresholds yourself.

Comment: yeah, it could be an external lybrary, or just the classes that I can implemment on my code in another package for example!

Comment: Yes either is fine, if you want to make it in your own code it is easy to set up regular expressions to test/limit special characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont't want to use external libs.. you can check it yourself.. Something like this:

```
   public void onSubmitClicked(View v) 
    { 
        String pass = passwordEditText.getText().toString(); 
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pass) || pass.length < [YOUR MIN LENGTH]) 
        { 
            passwordEditText.setError("You must more characters in your password"); 
            return; 
        }
        if(....){
              // do other controls here
        }


    }
```

Comment: That is what i was thinking, but what about checking if the password contains special chars? I am looking for a function to do that trying to put apart "for" loops or pre defined String arrays...